# train/test split with repeated measures

Tags: r, random, random-forest, training-data

I want to try a random forest on this data where y = happy after x = ate. Some of these people were lucky and got two free meals, while some only got one. Could I use rsample to make sure that the same id (in this case 5) does not appear in both the train and test split? If not, how should I do it?

```
library(tibble)
library(rsample)

set.seed(123)
dframe <- tibble(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,7), 
                 ate = sample(c("cookie", "slug"), size = 10, replace = TRUE),
                 happy = sample(c("yes", "no"), size = 10, replace = TRUE))


dframe_split <- initial_split(dframe, strata = "happy")
dframe_train <- training(dframe_split)
dframe_test <- testing(dframe_split)
```

Created on 2018-10-11 by the reprex package (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

As of `rsample 0.0.2`, the only documented way of performing a split like this using this library seems to be the `group_vfold_cv` function, example:

```
resamples <- group_vfold_cv(dframe, group='id', v=3)
lapply(resamples$splits, training)
lapply(resamples$splits, testing)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I'd prefer to split without folds though. You wouldn't by any chance know how I could do this without using rsample?

Comment: @stapperen How about just picking the first fold out of the ones generated by `group_vfold_cv`?

Comment: I should mention that I'm not very experienced with R (or machine learning). I'm having som trouble figuring how to use the output from `group_vfold_cv` like that. I also came across caret::groupKFold which appears to do the same thing. I guess my main problem is that I don't really know how to use k-folds for crossvalidation, that's why I just want a "simple" split.